# How to model which fixed effect is most responsible for variation in the DV?

Tags: mixed-model, clustering, fixed-effects-model, robust

Let's say I have data on firm revenue among multinational firms.  I want to test the question of what explains more variation in revenue: firm culture or country-culture.

A bit confused as to the best way to model this.  Should I run a mixed effects model with random intercepts for firm and country? Should I simply add fixed effects for firm and country and compare the average sum of squares for each model?

Comment: In some special circumstances, such as designed experiments, this is a meaningful question.  But in most others it is not.  Compare it to a question like "which is more responsible for holding up a bridge--the concrete or the rebar that reinforces it?"  The answer is *neither,* because together they make the bridge stand and without either one it would collapse.  Multiple regression with non-orthogonal regressors is like this, too: you cannot uniquely assign a proportion of the variation in the response to each regressor.

Comment: I don't follow what you might mean by "firms from the same company," nor do I understand how "average effects" might be related to "variation in revenue."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit a fixed effects model with firm and country as factor. But do not compare the coefficients. You need to compare the SS (sum of square) that firm and country explained.

Comment: and is this different from fitting a mixed effects model of the form revenue ~ (1 | country / firm) ?

Comment: in trying to fit both fixed effects in a felm model, i'm getting the error: the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite.  I think this is because after controlling for firm and country, there is no variability left in the model as there is only one firm per country.  Is that right?  

I get the error "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations" if I try to fit the above mixed effects model

Comment: For mixed effect model, the explained variation is presented by the variance of random intercepts. I have no idea how to test two variances (variance of culture specific intercept vs variance of country specific intercept) are equal. But for fixed effect model, F test will work.

Comment: "there is only one firm per country" then you cannot do anything on comparing firm culture vs country-culture. Based on "multinational firms", I thought there are more than one firm in at least several countries.

Comment: i'm sorry -- i mean to say that the SAME firm is not in a country more than once.  But a single country has lots of distinct firms.   Yet, for some reason, whenever I fit a country fixed effect, I am getting "the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite"

Comment: Fit a model with country only, to see if that rank-deficient appears or not.